# How to Limit The Amount of Rows a Single Unique ID can Have?/Limited Game Inventory For Text Game

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, mysql-python

I'm currently building a discord.py game bot/MMORPG bot with a MySQL database to store all user information and stuff. I plan to create an inventory system but I've come across a problem.

**My plan is to create/insert a row every time a player obtains a new item.** For example, let's say a player defeats a big boss and he obtains a new item. **I want to insert a new row that contains his unique discord userid and then the id of the item he has.** However, I've come across a problem. **How do I limit the amount of rows/slots/inventory spaces that can be created?**

I want 20 to be the default maximum amount of items a player can store in their inventory/database, but I don't know how to do that as I'm not very familiar with database structures yet. Can someone help me out? I'd really appreciate it.

Sample Code:

```
player_info (Table for User Info)
   userid
items (Table for Item Attributes)
   itemid (id of item)
   item_name (name of the item)
   item_stats (item attack damage / defense)
player_inv (Table to sync up item attributes and userid)
   player_id (id of player who has item)
   itemid (id of the item the player has)
```

So I want to insert rows with playerid and itemid in the player_inv table. I got this idea from stackexchage.com :>

Comment: I hope this question provides enough detail. Feel free to ask more questions

Comment: Please add sample table data which helps to explain your question.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: A sample code has been added :)

Comment: All I need to know, is how to set a limit, can you do that?

Comment: Check the duplicate link for some options.

Comment: That's actually the link to the last question I asked. It was closed due to lack of detail.